# How to assign in a method that I need data in a left join in yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

How to assign in a method that I need data in a left join in yii2?

I have a sql query :

```
 $query
                ->leftJoin('oper_coming', 'oper_coming.product_id = ' . $product_id)
                ->leftJoin('oper_adjustment', 'oper_adjustment.product_id = ' . $product_id)
                ->leftJoin('oper_consumption', 'oper_consumption.product_id = ' . $product_id)
                ->andWhere(['in', 'operations.id', ['oper_coming.transaction_id', 'oper_adjustment.transaction_id', 'oper_consumption.transaction_id']])
            ->groupBy('operations.id');
```

How do I assign values ​​from left join?
Yii2 is perceived as a string.

```
  ->andWhere(['in', 'operations.id', ['oper_coming.transaction_id', 'oper_adjustment.transaction_id', 'oper_consumption.transaction_id']])
```

And I need values ​​to be substituted from left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, always use alias for your tables(or almost always), for the sake of cleanlines and for the sake of your fingers.

```
->leftJoin('oper_coming oc', , 'oc.product_id = ' . $product_id)
```

Now instead of `oper_coming.transaction_id` you could use `oc.transaction_id`.

Second, SQL does not work like that, if you want to have all the IDs inside your andWhere you must do a sub `SELECT` to first get all that IDs desired.

But you cold do it different without a subselect with an `INNER JOIN`.

Change all your `leftJoin` for `innerJoin` and then add a check for the ID of the tables to not be null like:

```
->andWhere(['IS NOT', 'oper_coming.transaction_id', null])
->andWhere(['IS NOT', 'oper_adjustment.transaction_id', null])
->andWhere(['IS NOT', 'oper_consumption.transaction_id', null])
```

Comment: `->andWhere('operations.id IN (oper_coming.transaction_id, oper_adjustment.transaction_id, oper_consumption.transaction_id )')` 
I found this solution. 
Thanks for the tips. I will consider them.